# Explicit matrix form for the Cartan generators of $F_4$

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider the exceptional Lie group $F_4$. I want to represent this group in terms of matrices. In particular, I am interested in a maximal torus.

The first non-trivial representation of this group is $26$-dimensional, and the Cartan sub-algebra is $4$-dimensional. Therefore, the maximal torus is generated by four $26\times26$ matrices. Is the explicit form of these matrices available somewhere? Or how can I construct it myself?

Comment: Have you heard of the Freudenthal-Tits(-Vinberg) "magic square"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_magic_square Also, is your setup over the complex, or real, or an arbitrary field; and except in the first case, are you looking for the split form, or a compact form, or all forms ..?

Comment: Hi @TorstenSchoeneberg, thank you for your comment. I didn't know about the square, but it sounds neat. I will give it a read. And I am interested in the compact real form.